# Unable to read content of .txt using fs

Tags: node.js, fs

I am using fs mudule to read .txt file content , but the result always empty . My .txt file do has content in it could any one give me a hand pls ? This is my test code :

```
var fs = require("fs");

var content = "";
fs.readFile("2.txt", "utf8", function(err, data){
  if(err) {
    return console.log("fail", err);
  }
  content = data;
});

console.log(content);
```

The `content` is empty in console .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: You can use [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) if you want the synchronous version of `fs.readFile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing the result too early. You should log the result in the `readFile` callback.

```js
var fs = require("fs");

var content = "";
fs.readFile("2.txt", "utf8", function(err, data){
  if(err) {
    return console.log("fail", err);
  }
  content = data;
  console.log(content);
});
// The console log below will be executed right after the readFile call. 
// It won't wait the file to be actually read.
// console.log(content);
```

Or you can write the same logic like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

async function main() {
  try {
    const content = await fs.promises.readFile('2.txt', 'utf8');
    console.log(content);
  } catch (ex) {
    console.trace(ex);
  }
}

main();
```